# Global supply chains became seized up

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, ditransitive-verbs

This is a sentence from [an APNews article](https://apnews.com/article/coronavirus-pandemic-business-health-prices-inflation-bd71ae9e491907a51956c1d4eb07fb90).

> Global supply chains **became seized up**.

I think the part in bold should be 'seized up' because 'seize up' is not a transitive verb.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Both are possible with little difference in meaning though the grammar is different, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, “seized up” functions as an adjective, describing “global supply chains.” [This website](https://tutoring.ucdavis.edu/agg/adjectives-verbs) explains more if you’re looking for further information on how that works.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be helpful if you gave the reason that "seized up" is adjectival and not verbal.